# Getting ngClick to work on dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I can't seem to figure out why the `ng-click` directive isn't working on copied DOM elements.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BkRqa/4/

I can click on `+ Insert new fieldset`, but the buttons to remove added fieldsets are not working.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div id="education">
            <button class="add-button" ng-click="cloneField($event)">+ Insert new field</button>
            <!-- I want to make copies of .control-fieldset -->
            <div class="control-fieldset">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="name_0">School</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name[0]" id="name_0">
                    <!-- I want to remove copies of .control-fieldset -->
                    <button class="remove-button" ng-click="removeField($event)">-</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
(function () {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.cloneField = function (event) {
            var fieldHtml = $(event.target).parent().find(".control-fieldset").first().clone();
            $(event.target).parent().append(fieldHtml);
        };

        $scope.removeField = function (event) {
            $(event.target).remove();
        }
    }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cloned fields are being inserted into the DOM but not compiled by Angular. This means that the directives they contain have not been parsed and so the `ng-click` is not working on the cloned elements. So the compile should be done manually:

```
$scope.cloneField = function (event) {
    var fieldHtml = $(event.target).parent().find(".control-fieldset").first().clone();
    // Compile, then append the compiled element instead of the uncompiled
    var compiledElement = $compile(fieldHtml)($scope);
    $(event.target).parent().append(compiledElement);
};
```

Don't forget to inject the `$compile` service into the controller.

Also, since the button is the target of the event, you'll need to change your remove function to target the button's parent to remove any given cloned fieldset:

```
$scope.removeField = function (event) {
    $(event.target).parent().remove();  // Remove the whole cloned element
}
```

**Demo:** [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/GqPNy/)